# Jquery is not working properly in elecron.js

Tags: jquery, electron

I have just started to learn the `Electron` and I want to use `Jquery` in my app.

This is the simple alert demo.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Fontawesome CDN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css"
integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Custom styles-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
<!-- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag -->
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/parsley.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {      
  $("#btn-submit").click(function () {
    console.log("Button was clicked.");        
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate="">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="card">         
      <div class="card-body">
        <form>              
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" id="btn-submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>         
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add this line of code above `<script> code.`

```
 <script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('../assets/js/jquery.min.js');
 </script>
```